# usleep busy waiting

Tags: c++

started to experience with some real time threads.
I just sent my thread to sleep by calling usleep(TIME).
This will guarantee the thread to sleep for at least TIME.
I now measured with TIME= 10ms and got a gaussian function with an expected value of µ=10,1ms
The second measuring with TIME = 1us: I get a big peak at 4us.

So why is the second measurement not gaussian? My first idea was, the thread does not really sleep, but it makes a busy waiting instead. As stated [here (old beahavior)](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) there is no busy waiting. How can one explain the two curves?

Comment: Out of interest, what OS are you running to get that kind of resolution on system timers? The best I've seen usleep do is 4ms, not 4us... :)

Comment: What underlying system are you using for real-time threads? Have you seen [RTAI](https://www.rtai.org/)?

Comment: it is a xilinx fpga (PPC440) with linux 3.0 kernel

Answer (score 4):

Because of the *resolution* of timing functions. You said it yourself, it guarantees to sleep for at *least* that time. The reason why it can't guarantee to sleep exactly that amount of time is because it most likely operates in four-microsecond intervals.

The [man page](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/usleep.3.html) also mentions this phenomenon:

> The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or **by the granularity of system timers.**

Comment: so you mean there is (when sleeping for 1us) no other activity than sleeping and waking up, becaused it is not lengthened.

Comment: @user1264182: possibly, it's an implementation detail - it may _well_ amortise the delays such that it sometimes sleeps for four microseconds (eg. 25% of the time) and sometimes doesn't sleep (eg. 75% of the time). Personally, I 'd doubt it, it would introduce unnecessary complexity for a call already marked as having inaccuracies for small durations. Suffice to say that, at some lower bound, you will wait `X` microseconds no matter _what_ you ask for.

Comment: I expected that there will be a minimum of X us. The confusing thing is that no other thread starts when my thread is sleeping and the minimum sleeptime X will be missed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be explained with the overhead of the function call and perhaps a different method of waiting for a smaller interval. You can consider a constant the delay that cannot be avoided but can be subtracted for larger waits.